# How do I link to the create function in my controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this line in my routes.db file:

```
map.resources :things
```

I'm trying to create a link that will create a new thing. So far I've got

```
<%= link_to "add thing", things_path (:thingName => key)%>
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
Unknown action
No action responded to index. Actions: create and new
```

How do I do the link_to line so that it links to the create method instead of the index method? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to link to the new or the create action? The new action is:
<%= link_to "add thing", new_thing_path %>
The create action would not make sense here, since you don't have any data to inject into the new object? Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct. I am injecting some data, by doing (:thingName => key). Is this right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah! Well, in that case, you will be better off using a form consisting of hidden fields that contain the data you want submitted, or something similar - otherwise, you'll have to figure out how to attach the authenticity token and everything else. None of which is IMPOSSIBLE, but it might not be worth the trouble.

Comment: The mechanics of a form of hidden are in josh's post below. 100 forms on a single page is certainly going to be obnoxious to deal with - but then, so would 100 very complex link_to's. You CAN, btw, use the link_to to submit a form, you'd just need to set the method:

    link_to "add thing", things_path(*insert params here*), :method => :post

But, again, at that point, make sure you deal with the authenticity token, or it will just throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont want to create a resource through a link like that. Links are `HTTP GET` requests, which can be cached, and search engines will follow that link, resulting in database records being created incorrectly. You should only use `HTTP POST` requests to create a resource. To do that you need a `form`. If you already know the data to pass, you can use `hidden_field` to pass additional data

```
<% form_for Thing.new(:thing_name => key ) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :thing_name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but there might be a problem because I'm actually dynamically creating these save links, based on the result of another algorithm. There could potentially be hundreds of forms, would that be a problem?

Comment: If you are using a Javascript framework, you can do the equivalent http post in javascript.